# WCF Soap Faults: How to get Fault code on cilent

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, soapfault, faultcontract

I am just wondering if I can have an example of handling a Soap Fault on the cilent side and mainly how I can capture the Fault code?

This is what I have for my fault in the WCF side

```
 Throw New FaultException(Of String)("Value to large", New FaultReason("Reason: Value too large"), New FaultCode(23))
```

Correct?

the reason does come through correctly in the client side however, not the fault code. (I need code http 500 for example)

How do I go about trapping this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to provide a string for the faultcode 
The constructor doesn't accept an integer,
For instance you could provide http500 not 500 (that is not converted in correct XML) :

```
Throw New FaultException(Of String)("Value to large", New FaultReason("Reason: Value too large"), New FaultCode("http500"))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, so is my concept correct then? (Using the Fault Exception object)

Comment: Just take care of the detail of passing an integer, but a string for the faultcode. On the client side, you 'll catch a FaultException(Of String)

Comment: @user3428422 Did I answer your question ?

Comment: Not really, I like to certain that the code that I have done and that you reference is an correct example of  identifying a SOAP 1.1 fault and returning it to the client, however, you have been helpful so I will up vote you.

Comment: Here is a post that is pretty interesting regarding SOAP 1.1 Faultcode : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65008/net-wcf-faults-generating-incorrect-soap-1-1-faultcode-values?rq=1